Tauri project doesn't display/render correctly on Raspberry Pi 5
I am working on an interface that is going to run on a Raspberry Pi 5 (8G). Since i want the flexibility of React,HTML and CSS to create interfaces I decided to use Tauri to create it. Its supposed to be a fullscreen UI.
I started developing it on Windows and everything was going great until I was ready to continue developing on the Raspberry Pi. Ignoring most of the hastles of installing all dependencies and stuff, everything was going great until i started the program on it, only to see a mess of horizontal glitches running across the program window.
I know the interface is working since every time i interact with the known locations of the buttons, the horizontal lines change a little, but for some reason it just wont display like its supposed to.
Also, i am syncing the project on all machines via Github.
In case it might be helpful I'll include the output of the "npm run tauri info" command:

OS: Debian 12.0.0 x64

webkit2gtk-4.0: 2.44.3

rsvg2: 2.54.7

rustc: 1.81.0

cargo: 1.81.0

rustup: 1.27.1

Rust toolchain: stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

node: 22.9

npm: 10.8.3

tauri[Rust]: 1.8.0

tauri-build[Rust]: 1.5.5

wry[Rust]: 0.24.11

tao[Rust]: 0.16.10

@tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.6.0

@tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.6.2

build-type: bundle

CSP: unset

distDir: ../dist

Framework: React

bundler: Vite


I have tried:

uninstalling and re-installing all dependencies
delete and create again the Tauri project using the existing React project.
building it on the Raspberry to test if it continues to behave (it does)
tested it on a VM with Ubuntu to test if the problem is Linux (it works like it should)
_ Formated SD and started from scratch on the SD Card with a brand new Raspbian OS install (no luck either)

I also ran the project just on react and a local IP:port ("npm run dev") and it works fine on the browser.
My theories are:

that the Tauri project, most likely, has some code that is only compatible with X86 architecture, and the build process just skips it.

There might be some trouble with the display, as its a non-standard resolution (1024 x 600) and it might be wrecking havoc on the GPU (display: https://a.co/d/0lBreWr ), but it doesnt get fixed setting the app as non-fullscreen or changing the resolution of the display output

Tauri backend must be doing some weird rendering and fails spectacularly (when executing "npm run tauri dev" the desktop app opens, but it also enables a local IP:Port, opening that with the browser shows the application displaying correctly at the same time the desktop one is glitching)


Other notes:

I can "zoom" via touch on the glitchy desktop interface and it appears that i can zoom, but, obviously, its still a mess of lines
the lines appear to also be somewhat diagonal (going down from left to right)


Update:
I have also tried creating a new tauri project from scratch, and still, the "example" project that is created with the project also has the glitches
This is either a problem with the "npm run tauri dev" when its run directly on the Raspberry or a problem with Tauri itself running on Arm architecture
Probably i am doing something wrong too, so i will be trying to follow the "cross-Platform Compilation" process on the documentation just to check (i just didnt want to compile on a different machine until now)

Update: After much testing, i gave up Tauri as the framework for the project.
I migrated the React Project to Electron and, apart from some initial bugs and just the usual extra research, the project ended up executing and performing great.
So, at least for this situation, Tauri is not recommended.
Raspberry Pi 5, 8GB, Raspbian OS, Fullscreen app on small 7" touch 1024x600 hdmi display.
